# Converting string to json array with sqlite data base

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swifty-json

Hello I am storing live api data in sqlite table and after that I am retrieving again when user turn on internet I retrieving successfully in string but then i want to convert that data in json array like below

**Expected Output**

```
[{"properties_id":"1234","house_number":"1"},{"properties_id":"1234","house_number":"2"}]
```

i have tried to convert i will show you code which i tried but i am getting wrong output like below

**OutPut Which i get**

```
[["17", "1", "1234"], ["18", "2", "1234"]]
```

Here is my Code

```
var mainLocalArray = [Any]()

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! ProjectsTableViewCell
            let name = propertyLocalData[indexPath.row].house_number
            cell.lblProjectsName.text = "\(name!)"
            cell.viewVisitView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 86/255, green: 35/255, blue: 127/255, alpha: 1)
            let id = propertyLocalData[indexPath.row].id
            let pro_ID  = propertyLocalData[indexPath.row].proID
            let housnumber = propertyLocalData[indexPath.row].house_number
            let arrayLocal = ["\(id)", "\(pro_ID)", housnumber!] as [Any]
            print(arrayLocal)
            self.mainLocalArray.append(arrayLocal)
            print(mainLocalArray)
            return cell
    }
```

I am creating array of values which I get from data base and appending in other mainlocalarray but how to convert in json array not able to understand please help someone.

Comment: Also, the expected output appears to be an array of dictionaries. What you are doing is converting the string to an array of arrays. Please read on about the data types and Encodable protocols. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/encodable ; https://www.raywenderlich.com/382-encoding-decoding-and-serialization-in-swift-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cellForRowAt` is absolutely the wrong place to convert the data.

Simple solution with the `Encodable` protocol

- Delete

  ```
  var mainLocalArray = [Any]()


  let arrayLocal = ["\(id)", "\(pro_ID)", housnumber!] as [Any]
  print(arrayLocal)
  self.mainLocalArray.append(arrayLocal)
  print(mainLocalArray)
  ```
- In your struct (the type of `propertyLocalData`) add `Encodable` and `CodingKeys`

  ```
  struct MyStruct : Encodable {

  ...

      private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case id = "properties_id", house_number }

  ... }
  ```
- In a method (**not** in `cellForRow`) encode the data source array

  ```
  do {
     let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(propertyLocalData)
     let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
     print(jsonString)
  } catch { print(error) }
  ```

PS: Drop SwiftyJSON.